# What the switch protocol based layer are?

Tags: osi

What the switch protocol based layer are? For the packet switching and virtual circuit. The basis of them.

Comment: As much as I've just written a whole answer to this question, it now occurs to me that your question does read a bit like a homework question. If it is homework, I'm sorry to say it is off topic here. Also, I'm sorry to say (maybe not as sorry, but a little sorry) that my answer probably won't help as much for homework, since it's based on the real world and not the school world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a reminder: The OSI network model is **only a model**. It was not used to define any of the most common network technologies or protocols. The OSI protocols it was used for are almost entirely unused. TCP/IP was developed using a different model that can be related to the OSI model, but even the TCP/IP model is still just a model. These models are certainly very useful in talking about and understanding how networking works, but many technologies do not fit neatly into any one layer of the OSI model.

The most classic example of a circuit-switched network is the North American ISDN network for telephony (and of course its analog predecessor, often called "POTS" for "plain old telephone service"). Probably the best layer to think of for ISDN is layer 1. That being said, the generic concept of circuit switching is not layer specific. It would make little sense for a circuit switched protocol to be encapsulated (in layer terms, encapsulation is how one layer rides on top of another layer) in a packet switched protocol, but it is possible for circuit switched protocols to ride on top of other circuit switched protocols, which would be modeled as more the one layer being circuit switched.

The same goes for packet switching. Again, there are some very famous packet switched protocols, the most famous being TCP/IP and Ethernet. The suite that comprises TCP/IP does not map to a single layer of the OSI model, and is most commonly modeled in layers 3 and 4, while Ethernet is considered a layer 2 protocol. Since those are not the only packet switched protocols, there is no single answer to the question of what network layer packet switching would be done on.

"Virtual circuit" is a more general term typically used to describe a dedicated connection encapsulated inside a (usually packet) switched protocol. A virtual circuit is meant to behave to the user as if it is either circuit switched or not switched at all (point to point). This is another case where the OSI model does not yield one simple answer. From the provider's standpoint, a virtual circuit would likely be modeled best as a layer 3 or 4 protocol, or at least be encapsulated inside a layer 2 or 3 protocol. Most virtual circuits are meant to operate as layer 1 connections for the end users. This is analogous to a VPN, where one way to look at it is a full OSI stack contained inside a second partial (or possibly full) OSI stack.